# unknown ansi escape codes - )0[, ?7h and ?7l

Tags: terminal, xterm, ansi-escape, vt100

So I'm seeing some ANSI escape codes I'm unfamiliar with in some output.

```
\\x1B)0[
\\x1B[?7h
\\x1B[?7l
```

http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php says that `\\x1B[=7h` and `\\x1B[=7l` will set and reset (respectively) the mode to enable line wrapping but those have ='s and not ?'s so idk how applicable that is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps some sort of character set issue, where `?` is supposed to be `=`?

Comment: That's what I thought but the hex of the character I'm getting back is `\\x3F`, which is the hex for `?` in ASCII.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code Do Control-F "[?". You'll see that ``\\x1B[?5h`` and ``\\x1B[?5l`` flash the terminal screen. Perhaps replacing 5 with 7 flashes something else. The first line there seems completely invalid though, since none of the escape codes begin with ``)``

Comment: By the way, the OP's cited URL describes `ansi.sys`, which is only vaguely related to VT100.

Answer (score 1):

The first `\\x1B)0` (if not misquoted) could be one of the character-set controls:

```
        C = 0  -> DEC Special Character and Line Drawing Set.
....
ESC ) C   Designate G1 Character Set (ISO 2022, VT100).
          The same character sets apply as for ESC ( C.
```

The `?` indicates a *private mode* setting.  ISO-6429 ([ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-048.pdf)) defines four: `<`, `>`, `?` and `=`.  The corresponding *mode* (still quoting *[XTerm Control Sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html)*):

```
CSI ? Pm h
      DEC Private Mode Set (DECSET).
...
        Ps = 7  -> Wraparound Mode (DECAWM).
```

The application is supposed to pause briefly between changing this between reverse-video and back to the normal state.

Comment: OP's sequences have 7, so that's Wraparound Mode (DECAWM).